# get filename of file uploaded through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, upload, header

My problem is quite simple.

I am writing an uploader class in php and have decided to include support for ajax uploads.

Using firefox, I detected that a header X-File-Name is sent. I am using a 3rd party javascript library for the uploads, and it sends the filename in a query string to the php script.

What I wish to know is, is there a consistent means of getting the filename like through the X-File-Name that is consistent with all ajax requests or I need users to specify the name of the file.

I can ask users to specify, but I would love to have a consistent method.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of Ajax uploads, can you specify? There are multiple upload methods informally called "Ajax upload"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems nothing is concrete in the world of xhr. I therefore resulted to using the `X-File-Name` header if I found it but requiring a user submitted filename. Uploads are read from the input stream.

Answer (score -3):

I believe `$_FILES[inputname][name]` is what you're looking for, where `inputname` is the name given to the file upload input box.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: I'm talking about ajax requests. Files are sent over the input stream in php so the I doubt the globals $_FILES is set.

Comment: Style niggle: $_FILES['inputname']['name'] is much preferred, as your code is incorrect (unless you want to use the global constant 'name' to get the array key - which you don't here).

Comment: I doubt this will work since the client side has to inform the php script that the data is a file through the sent headers. I don't think this is true of all plugins and will lead to trouble. In actual fact, I read the input stream for files. 
Note. I am trying to develop a portable class not one for personal use only.