# How to display name of file after file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a a form which contains a file input, upload button and cancel button:

**UPDATE:**

```
    <form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='stopImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
    <p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'><label>Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label>
    <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>
    </p>
    <p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'>
    <label><input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>
    </p> 
<p><span class='list></span></p>
    <iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe>
    </form>
```

Now what I want is that if an image has finished uploading, at the bottom of this form I want the name(s) of the file that have been uploaded. Is this possible? For Example, I upload Images/file1.png, the name file1.png is stored at the bottom after uploading, I upload user/file2.jpg the name file2.jpg is stored at the bottom below file1.png and etc.

I have uploading of files all sorted out in php and javascript. Below is javascript code after uploading is complete:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fileImage').bind('change', handleFileSelect, false);
});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name; //save the name for future use
}
function stopImageUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
  result = '<span class="msg">The file ('+localStorage["fname"]+') was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
    localStorage["fname"] = undefined; //remove the temporary variable

      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: So, you want the [JavaScript](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-in) way, or the [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921843/get-filename-of-file-uploaded-through-ajax) way?

Comment: I want it done javascript way because the php script is on a seperate page to the form

Comment: Check out the demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/xUzcS/ (using HTML5 File API)

Answer (score 0):

### The JavaScript Way

If you are targeting modern browsers (no more IE6789), well, [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is the right thing for you to fetch file name! It is easy to use, and no mess in your codes.

Check out the demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/xUzcS
Is this what you want?

But if you want to support that old IE6, then sorry, you have to go the AJAX way, or use VBscript. (not recommended)

### ADDED

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    localStorage["fname"] = files[0].name; //save the name for future use
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);​
```

Then:

```
if (success == 1){
    result = '<span class="msg">The file ('+localStorage["fname"]+') was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
    localStorage["fname"] = undefined; //remove the temporary variable
}
```

This may work for you, since I don't know the whole html.

Comment: Hi, that is what I want but I want it to display not the file in the file input, but the file which has been uploaded from the file input. So the name should only be displayed after uploading is complete

Comment: No, the file name is showing in both the `<input>` and `<output>` tag. See screenshot:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/JUT8s.png  You can save the file name in variables and show it when it done uploading.

Comment: Hi, Derek, sorry I didn't comment very well in the comment above. What I meant is that i want the name of the file to appear below the file input after the file has been uploaded, not after the user has selected a file after clicking on browse button. I know you have shown me code in jsfiddle but in my code can you show me the code to achieve this so that it outputs the name of the file after uploading of the file is successful. I will definetly mark it as best answer if you can achieve this in my code :)

Comment: Is the `function stopImageUpload(success)` on the same page as the uploading page?

Comment: the function is on the same page as the form but in the uploading page (seperate page), it calls on the function after uploading like below: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>`

Comment: does function handleFileSelect(evt) go inside the stopImageUpload() function? Also where it says evt.target.files, as my name attribute is fileImage should it be evt.target.fileImage?

Comment: `handleFileSelect` leave it outside, and `evt.target.files` dont change.

Comment: Last question before testing, I want the name of the file to appear in the bottom of my form (my form can be seen in question), how can I add it to the span tag "list" rather than in results?

Comment: You are smart. You can think of it by yourself. Keep trying and at the end you will succeed. ;)

Comment: It keeps displaying (null!) rather than the name of the file. I had to change `document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);` to `$('.fileImage').bind('change', handleFileSelect, false);` but that can't be the reason right?

Comment: `localStorage["fname"]` or `files[0].name` is returning `null`?

Comment: I don't know, it is just saying null in brakets, nope in error console

Comment: I heard it is because I am using a change event with an onsubmit event. is there is a problem with handleFileSelect being called both on change and on submit. it is not saying null now, it is saying undefined. I updated code in my question so you can see what it looks like.